# How to convert a single key within a list of dictionaries to a string on the fly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a REST API to manage some storage appliances.

I have the following snippet that returns a list of dictionaries. The dictionaries in the list are completely identical in structure and number/types of keys. I want to concatenate a single key from each dictionary into a string:

```
result.getJSONData()['chassis']  # returns a list of dictionaries
```

The actual value I want to concatenate is this (here I'm just looping thru the list and printing the key I want to concatenate):

```
for chassis in result.getJSONData()['chassis']:
    print chassis['name']
```

Here is where I want to concatenate and use this string (one of my many attempts at doing this):

```
log.info("  %s: discovered the following chassis: %s" % (self.name, result.getJSONData()['chassis']['name'].join(", ")))
```

This is a threaded application so I'm trying to make log entries as autonomous as possible, hence why I'm trying to display this all in one log entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (or generator expression in this case):

```
', '.join(chassis['name'] for chassis in result.getJSONDATA()['chassis'])
```

Comment: Ahh that's it. Couldn't recall the exact syntax and had trouble searching for it. Thx, I'll give this a shot.